# C# Interface to Existing Managed C++ class

Tags: c#, managed-c++

I have a Managed C++ class (Very old legacy code) that I am busy abstracting.
I need to build a C# interface to the class.

In the Managed C++ class I have the following:

```
property SomeClass^ SomeClass { SomeClass^ get(); }
```

In the interface class (C#) would the following be the correct declaration:

```
SomeClass someClass { get; }
```

I'm unsure how to handle the reference part (^), since C# doesn't seem to allow

```
ref SomeClass someClass { get; }
```

Would it be necessary to take into account that the Managed C++ function returns a reference, or would it be handled internally?
Or am I just missing something completely.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes

```
    SomeClass someClass { get; }
```

is correct. The caret doesn't mean "ref" in the C# sense, ref is spelled % in C++/CLI. Caret just means "managed pointer", a distinction that is automatically figured out by the syntax of C# based on the types involved.

A^ in C++/CLI will always be A in C#.

Comment: Thank you very much for confirming! I appreciate the feedback.